# Can not checkout a branch with uppercased file in Intellij Idea and Webstorm (Windows)

Tags: git, intellij-idea, webstorm

- Choose some file in your project and rename it to another case (app.js -> App.js)
- Commit it
- Try to get back to previous commit
- You'll see a warning notification with the text "Some untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout. Please move or remove them before you can checkout."

When I used Ubuntu, there were no such problems. I know also that Windows' file system is case insensitive so maybe it causes the issue.

I also tried to change case sensitivity for git like this:

`git config core.ignorecase false`

but it didn't help

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

> Some untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout. Please move or remove them before you can checkout

And what is the actual file listed as preventing checkout? App.js should not be an untracked one after the rename.

Also just tested with such a rename, and checking out pre-rename state works fine. Does it work at the command prompt for you?